# How to provide PC's VPN to Android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, vpn

Windows 11, default Android emulator that comes with AndroidSDK. No Android Studio installed.
Need to access corporate servers that are accessible only through corporate VPN (Forti).
With VPN connected I can access them on Windows, but can't access on emulated Android device.

Tried connecting to VPN both before and after emulator cold boot, none helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading Forti using the emulator play store? Click [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortinet.forticlient_vpn)?
Or any other downloads from [here](https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads#vpn)